# A proxy that bridges simultaneous clients to a single connection

Tags: linux, sockets, networking, proxy, vpn

I am looking for a tool (under linux) that will allow me to set up an end to end proxy that accepts multiple simultaneous clients on one port at one end, forwards the data to the other end with a *single* connection then "expands" the connection at the other end to connect back to a service that accepts multiple connections. To clarify, here is a diagram of what I want to achieve:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgTMd.png

(apparantly I need more then 10 rep to have the image embedded in this page)

If you're interested, the reason why I am attempting to do this is because I want to build a system that would make it easier to tunnel over arbitrary protocols, as long as the protocol supports some way to send some message from one end to another. I would put the system in between proxy end A and proxy end B in the diagram above.

Here is an example of how I want it to work:

First I will run the following commands

`mkfifo backpipe`

`nc -l  7778 0<backpipe | tee f1 | nc localhost 7777 | tee f2 >backpipe`

The "server proxy" will be running on port 7777.

The "client proxy" that the application will connect to will be running on port 8080

The client proxy will connect to port 7778

Solve for "server proxy" and "client proxy"

Comment: You can use a GRE/VPN/L2TP tunnel between the two Proxy servers and route the data through them.

Comment: @EdwardH Oh, I wasn't aware VPN protocols operated in this way. After poking around, setting up a vpn tunnel with openvpn and intercepting the communications seems to be perfect for what I want to do. I will investigate more. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'm having issues implementing a vpn solution. If I can get it working, it will be the most elegant solution, but I will continue to look elsewhere to get a solution too.

Answer (score 0):

OpenSSH already supports this with the `-D` option:

```
ssh -D <port> -l username remotehost
```

A SOCKS server will listen for connections on  and forward them to the other end of the SSH connection.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm having issues with getting this working, so I can't verify this just yet, but I did manage to get something working with the -L option. I'm trying to reproduce this success again, but I am so tired that I have forgotton what I did to get it working and my bash history is not being that helpful. I'll get some sleep and take another look tomorrow.

Comment: `-L` does not do SOCKS. It just forwards connections on a single port to a single remote destination.

Comment: I was probably too hasty in specifying it must be a SOCKS proxy; it was just what I was looking into at the time. Any sort of proxy will do as long as it's implementation allows it to do what I desire. I've updated the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to code my own solution for the mean time. It's a bit of python code that accepts multiple clients and basically proxies the communication through the standard input/output. If anyone is interested, here's the code http://pastebin.com/1E45Exsy

Don't trust this code to work perfectly. I have not tested it properly and it doesn't handle disconnecting clients.

I will continue to search for a more elegant and robust solution, but this should do in the meantime. I'll post updates to the code here if I make them.